# How to force Emacs or pinentry to forget wrong GPG password?

Tags: mu4e, gpg

I use `mu4e`, `mu4e-send-delay` to send emails with a delay, GPG to store my SMTP authentication, and `pinentry` to access GPG files. When I am prompted for the GPG encryption password in the mini-buffer but am typing in another buffer and don't notice it, Emacs remembers that entry and keeps trying to open the GPG file with that wrong password. I then get the `*Error*` buffer next to my other buffer:

```
Error while decrypting with "/usr/local/bin/gpg":

gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: gcry_kdf_derive failed: Invalid data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

and a user dialog `Emacs-x86_64-10_14`, `Buffer *temp* modified; kill anyway?`, and buttons with `Yes` and `No`.

Emacs has the same behavior if I restart it, probably because `pinentry` remembers the password for the session.

How can I force Emacs or `pinentry` to prompt for a new password? And could I force that prompt to happen in a user dialog, which is more noticeable than the mini-buffer?

Comment: I don't use pinentry, so I cannot give you an exact recipe, but as it communicates with the gpg agent and has its own service, I'd start restarting the agent. `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

Comment: Yes, this works. I had tried `ps -ef | grep gpg` to find the process ID of `gpg-agent` (if it's running, it will return 2 process IDs, one for `gpg-agent` and one for the search process itself), and then kill it with `kill <process ID>`. This solution is much more elegant.

Comment: How about the prompt for the password to happen in a user dialog? Could I configure the `gpg-agent` to forget passwords that fail at decryption?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/586969/force-gpg-agent-to-forget-password/887987

Comment: What I do is having my passwords stored in encrypted files and telling the helper application (mbsync/msmtp) to use the password stored there in its conf file as result of a command like `gpg --quiet --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty --decrypt pwd-file.gpg`. The app will fail to login if you make typos, but you won't have to mess up with the agent recalling wrong passwords, it'll only recall it if it succeed.

Comment: @Muihlinn I read [the Gnu appendix on GPG](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/auth/GnuPG-and-EasyPG-Assistant-Configuration.html) and [the GPG directions](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT) but I'm still confused how I set up your commands. Is `mbsync/msmtp` the helper you use instead of `gpg-agent` or `epa`? Can you point me in the direction of setting up `gpg-agent` or one of your helpers?

Comment: I set up this part years ago and I didn't recalled the gory details of it, so I looked upon it in detail. In the end looks like I do use gnome-pinentry nowadays but I'm prettry sure that I installed it later for something else. Allow me a few days to thread it back and elaborate a proper response @miguelmorin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pinentry is only an interface, it doesn't keep any passphrase or permission, and neither does Emacs. It's GPG-agent that manages the ropes. For example, if the time expires or the process dies, you'll have to authenticate again.  So just kill the agent:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

More info at the [gnupg manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT).

Comment: Can you elaborate why this works?

Comment: I've edited the response.